# Как в коде переключить раскладку soft-клавиатуры в Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, клавиатура

Чтобы либо при каждом её вызове либо по дефолту была русская раскладка. Либо через настройки клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void printInputLanguages() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        List<InputMethodInfo> ims = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
    for (InputMethodInfo method : ims) {
        List<InputMethodSubtype> submethods = imm.getEnabledInputMethodSubtypeList(method, true);
        for (InputMethodSubtype submethod : submethods) {
            if (submethod.getMode().equals("keyboard")) {
                String currentLocale = submethod.getLocale();
                //Вот тут будет нужная локаль, в Вашем случае должно прийти "ru"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Он показал, что всё печально. 
 
`imm.setCurrentInputMethodSubtype(submethod)`

требует привилегии android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, которая разрешена только для системных приложений, что мне не подходит.
Так что остаются варианты - найти и скачать русскоязычную клавиатруру отдельно, либо пришпандорить самодельную. 
Странно, что в настройках стандартной гугловской клавиатуры не нашлось пункта типа "раскладка по умолчанию".